# iOS Detect Purchased Version to Change Functionality

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, iad

Is it possible / allowed to detect one version a user originally purchased my app? Or conversely be able to detect new purchasers?

I am switching the app from paid to free and adding ads however ideally I would be able to detect those users who've already paid for the app and not add the ads.

Comment: If they are separate downloads within the app store, you'll want to just remove the ad-serving code in the free-version. If it's an in-app purchase, just have it unlock something- say, change something in NSUserDefaults. If they re-download it and "unlock" the paid version again Apple should make sure not to double-charge them (just like when you re-download an app you've already paid for)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's not possible. Detecting and not charging re-purchaser is as far as I know 100% on Apples side.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish what you want would be to have a free version in addition to the paid version. Anything else would be fairly error-prone.